# Подключения css фрейворков в проектах react

Tags: reactjs

я пытаюсь подключить сторонний фреймворк к реакту а конкретно [materializecss](https://materializecss.com/waves.html) эффект `waves` стили подключается но вот что с `javascript'ом` не понятно, как работать javascript компонентами: [проект](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pbj2yf)

Comment: Для реакта есть хорошая библиотека material-ui https://material-ui.com/

Comment: @meine Она сложная для новичка, например я там не нашел `Grid` -> `Container` -> `row` на 70% она очень сложная

Comment: Если посидеть 2-3 дня, то можно выучить без проблем, ну ладно, это уже Ваше дело, учить или нет, могу лишь пожелать успехов в начинаниях

Comment: Вот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499842/how-to-use-materialize-css-with-react) на этот вопрос с enSo, сделайте кто нибудь перевод